# Flutter Dio post Error Http status error [301]

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dio

```
String url = 'http://jaria.kg/apis/v1/create/';
    var response = await dio.post(url,
              data: formData,
              options: Options(
                  headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}));
          print(response.data);
          return response.data;
```

returns Http status error [301]

Comment: Please share the formData as well.

Comment: FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
    "title": titleController.text,
    "content": contentController.text,
    "number": numberController.text,
    "name": nameController.text,
    "address": addressController.text,
    "price": priceController.text == null ? 0 : priceController.text,
    "category": category,
    "region": region,
    "valute": valute,
    'images': _images
  });

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var response = await dio.post('http://jaria.kg/apis/v1/create/',
    data: formData,
    options: Options(
        followRedirects: false,
        validateStatus: (status) { return status < 500; },
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
    ),
);
```

Comment: Response: 301 Moved permanently nginx

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
var response = await dio.post(url, data: formData, options: Options(
        contentType: 'application/json',
        followRedirects: false,
        validateStatus: (status) => true,
        headers: {
          "Accept":"application/json",
        }
    ));
```

Also make sure formData is formatted properly, i.e. acceptable by your server

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.
In my case I just removed `/` at the end of the URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).